# Regex fro fetching the substring after nth _

Tags: regex, postgresql

I'm trying to write a regex for getting the substring after the late '_'.

I have written a regex but this is giving me the last '_' as well.

Regex written :

```
^((?:[^_]*\_){2})
```

**Input string**: harmeet_kaur_abc

**Regex output**: harmeet_kaur_

**Required output**: harmeet_kaur

Comment: why dont you just split on the underscore and take then parts of the result array after the nth underscore?

Answer (score 1):

You are including the second _ in the repetition.

You could either match only the first part:

```
SELECT REGEXP_MATCHES('harmeet_kaur_abc', '^[^_]*_[^_]*')
```

Or remove starting from the last underscore:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('harmeet_kaur_abc', '_[^_]*$', '')
```

Both will output

```
harmeet_kaur
```